# Use a sequence to populate a list and repeat the number by itself

Tags: python

Context: I'm learning python and I'd like to populate a list using `range()`. For example, if our `n` is 5, we would get `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]`.

I was able to get the desired output by inserting a sublist inside a list and then replicating the numbers for each sublist by i amount of times. Then, I used nested loops to remove the sublists so that we only get one list.

```
def repetition(n):
    sequence = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        sequence.insert(i, [i]*i) 

    flat_list = []
    for sublist in sequence: #for every sublist inside the list sequence
        for item in sublist: #get every item inside of the sublist
            flat_list.append(item) #append every item to a new flat_list

    return flat_list

repetition(5)
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this with as much "vanilla" python as possible (no `itertools`, etc). I've found similar SO posts regarding this, but I haven't found one yet that uses this example.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use [**`.extend`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `.insert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix to your approach is using `extend`:

```
def repetition(n):
    sequence = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sequence.extend([i]*i) 
        # OR:
        # for _ in range(i):
        #     sequence.append(i)
    return sequence
```

But then, you can have this with a nested comprehension:

```
def repetition(n):
    return [i for i in range(1, n+1) for _ in range(i)]

repetition(5)
# [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using strings:

```
def repetition(n):
    res = ""
    for i in range(n):
        res=res + i*str(i)
    return list(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 for loops to get the desired output

Code:

```
n = int(input())
ans=[]
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(i):
        ans.append(i)
print(ans)
```

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```